# Figure out which address a UDP message was addressed to

Tags: node.js, udp

Suppose we fire up a server to listen for UDP messages, using `0.0.0.0` to listen on any address:

```js
import dgram from 'node:dgram';
const server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
  // How to get the address the message was sent ***TO***?
});

server.bind(8989, '0.0.0.0');
```

When a message comes in, I can [inspect `rinfo` and get the remote address](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#event-message) and what not.  Is there any way to figure out which address the packet was addressed to?

Comment: There is a socket option to provide the source address, but I don't know whether `node.js` supports it. Look around.